# Alternative for symlink for Azure File Share

Tags: azure, azure-storage, symlink, azure-files

My application has a directory 'A' which is a symlink to another directory 'B' but I want to move directory 'B' to an Azure File share so that it becomes a central location and I am able to use this directory 'B' with other applications.

According to the document below Azure Files does not support symlinks so ofcourse even if I do create a symlink my application doesn't work properly. (I have tested this)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/features-not-supported-by-the-azure-file-service

I have even tried to create a virtual directory within my IIS application which also didn't seem to work.

Is there an alternative to symlink which I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mfsymlinks mount option, refer here for more details: [Cannot create symbolic links - ln: failed to create symbolic link 't': Operation not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-troubleshoot-linux-file-connection-problems#cannot-create-symbolic-links---ln-failed-to-create-symbolic-link-t-operation-not-supported)